# Unable to do a Flask redirect to external link in VPS / Webuzo Panel / Apache / Passenger

Tags: apache, flask, redirect, passenger

I have a route:

```
@app.route('/redirect_google2')
def redirect_google2():
    return redirect(f"https://www.google.com/search?q=teste")
```

In my computer I can of course access and be redirected.

But in my Linux Ubuntu VPS / Webuzo Panel / Using Apache and Passenger, I cannot.

The destination is (wrong):
https://myurl.com.br/search?q=teste

Because it should go to:
https://www.google.com/search?q=teste

I don't know if its apache related stuff or what? Please, can someone help?

Tried lot of modifications in the routes. But I'm suspecting this is another issue, related to the vps (configuration of the Server) itself.